# how can i show a Div and hide a form once the form has been submitted? i've tried jquery but it doesnt work. help me?

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, submit

how can i show a Div and hide a form once the form has been submitted? ive tried jquery but it doesnt work. help me? here is the code:

> website
>       
>       body {
>         background-color: black;
>         color: green;
>       }
>
> ```
> #theirname {
>   color:red;
>   font-size: 6.0em;
>   margin:auto;
>   text-align:center;
>   display:none;
> }
>
> #hellos {
>   color:yellow;
>   font-size:6.5em;
>   margin-top:auto;
>   text-align:left;
>   display:none;
> }
> #thanks {
>   color:yellow;
>   font-size:4.3em;
>   margin-right:20px;
>   text-align:right;
>   display:none;
> }
>
> #hello { 
>   border-style:groove; 
>   border-color: yellow; 
>   margin:auto;
>   text-align:center;
>   width:300px;
> }
>
> marquee {
>   color:yellow;
>   font-size:30px;
> }
> form {
>   text-align:center;
>   margin:auto;
>   margin-top:120px;
> }
> </style>
> <script>
> function handler() {
>   var div = document.getElementById('theirname');
>
>   var form = document.getElementById('fore');
>
>      div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
>      return false;
> }
>
> $(document).ready(function(){
>   $("#Fore").submit(function(e){
>     $("#fore").hide(slow);
>   $("#hellos").show(3000);
>   $("#theirname").show(3030);
>   $("#thanks").show(4000);
>   });
> });
>
> </script>
> </head>
>
> <body>
> <div id="hello">Welcome to here :D</div>
>
> <marquee behavior="scroll" scroll="left" bgcolor="red" onClick="">ill update this soon...</marquee>
>
> <div id="hellos">Hello,</div>
> <div id="theirname"></div>
> <div id="thanks">thank you for coming!</div>
>
> <form id="Fore" action="submit" method="post" onSubmit="return handler();">
> Your name: <input id="textbox" type="text" name="fname" size="20" />
> <input type="submit" value="post" />
> </form>
>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

here is so you can see what i mean. [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrawesome4ever/P2knf/)

Comment: +50 for the marquee...

Comment: what do you mean? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you has a error in your javascript:

change

```
$("#fore").hide(slow);
```

to

```
$("#Fore").hide('slow'); //  Your id is Fore and not fore
```

Comment: i just updated my code and also on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrawesome4ever/P2knf/10/), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: remove < script type = "text/javascript" >  and < /script> of your javascript box

Comment: it worked! @A.Wolff! :D do you know what was wrong with my code? please tell me, i'm trying to learn. :)

Comment: first your id was different than form id ('fore' -> 'Fore')
Second when call hide function with slow, you need to add apostrophe ('slow')
"It worked" is usually expressed on Stack Overflow by accepting the question  =p

Comment: @Mrawesome4ever I'm not the answerer... ;) Your jsFiddle needs to include jQuery and all other mistake is explain in this answer. As a good advice, always use console in debugging purpose to check for any error (f12 in browser on windows)

Comment: wow!  haha something so simple that has been bugging me for hours, you guys knew everything right away. Thank you guys again! :)

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks anyways, and okay. I'll keep that in mind from now on. Thank you again.

Comment: @brunozrk, when I run it on notepad and launch it that way then check why it doesn't work on Console it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". Whats wrong with it there? I've changed the changes that were wrong in jsfiddle but i left the <script type="text/javascript>" tag in. I've also tried using it without it. but it still wouldnt work.

Comment: nevermind about that, all i needed to add was <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> in the head. thank you all anyways.